# What is the right tense form here?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, past-simple, tense-agreement

> This is an idea **he had introduced** in his article which **would appear** six years later in a book by a different author.

Are the tenses right in the sentence? Here, we are talking about the second action that has not yet happened when the first action is happening. And the narration is happening in the present.

I am very confused about the right tenses to use here.
My main question would be about "would" Am I correct to use "would" here to refer to a future event that had not yet happened?

Comment: What's the context before it? We need that to know whether the past perfect applies

Comment: A discussion of an article which was written years ago by someone is happening now;; that article has an idea which appeared in a book much later than when the article was written.

Comment: I mean, please edit your question to include the sentences that came before this one so we have the grammatical context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different variations of this sentence you can create by mixing different tenses, and all would be correct. I would focus on making it as simple as possible by using the simple past tense:

> This is an idea he introduced in his article that appeared six years later in a book by a different author.